# How to split a json into multiple files using part of the date

Tags: python

I have a big json file holding weather data. each set has timestamp.
Now I want to split the json into multiple files using the month as filename: like 2021-10.json

The data look like this:

```
[
{
    'dt': 1633651200,
    'temp': 11.09,
    'feels_like': 10.66,
    'pressure': 1030,
    'humidity': 92,
    'dew_point': 9.84,
    'uvi': 0,
    'clouds': 98,
    'visibility': 10000,
    'wind_speed': 2.05,
    'wind_deg': 26,
    'wind_gust': 3.26,
    'weather': [
        {'id': 804, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'overcast clouds', 'icon': '04n'}
    ]
},
{
    'dt': 1633654800,
    'temp': 10.27,
    'feels_like': 9.75,
    'pressure': 1030,
    'humidity': 92,
    'dew_point': 9.03,
    'uvi': 0,
    'clouds': 100,
    'visibility': 10000,
    'wind_speed': 2.32,
    'wind_deg': 54,
    'wind_gust': 4.73,
    'weather': [
        {'id': 804, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'overcast clouds', 'icon': '04n'}
    ]
},...
```

First thing I did is to convert the timestamp into a date.
My code so far looks like this:

```
with open('data.json','r', encoding='utf8') as f:
# Read the file and convert it to a dictionary
d = json.load(f)
x = d['hourly']
rprint(x)
for json_obj in x:
    timestamp= json_obj['dt']
    dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    json_obj['dt'] = dt_obj
    rprint(dt_obj)
    filename=str(json_obj['dt'])+'.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as out_json_file:
        json.dump(json_obj, out_json_file, indent=4)
```

Has anybody an idea how I can put all the entries for one day into one json file.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider creating a temporary container to reorganize & hold related month data together like this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# ...open and parse json file

month_data = defaultdict(list)

for json_obj in hourly_data:
    timestamp = json_obj["dt"]
    # more useful to keep the datetime object as an object, not a string yet
    dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

    json_obj["dt"] = dt_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # if you haven't used `defaultdict` before, it allows skipping some
    # boilerplate code when creating dict entries that may not exist
    month_data[dt_obj.strftime("%Y-%m")].append(json_obj)

# month: '2021-10' (key), json_data: list of hourly/day data (value)
for month, json_data in month_data.items():
    with open(f"{month}.json", "w") as json_outfile:
        json.dump(json_data, json_outfile, indent=4)
```

***Edit:**

I see you asked for each *day* to be a separate file (your code was seeming to do it by month)... I think you can extrapolate my example to work for one JSON file per day. Let me know if you figure it out!

***Edit 2:**

In answer to your comment:

Initializing defaultdict with a default factory argument — `defaultdict(list)` — states that if a key is not found, that the defaultdict object should initialize the value of any non-existent key to an empty list. The equivalent code would look like:

```py
In [1]: default_list_dict = {}

In [2]: for key in ["a", "b", "c"]:
   ...:     if key not in default_list_dict:
   ...:         default_list_dict[key] = []
   ...:     default_list_dict[key].append(42)
   ...:

In [3]: default_list_dict
Out[3]: {'a': [42], 'b': [42], 'c': [42]}
```

In the line you asked about:

```py
month_data[dt_obj.strftime("%Y-%m")].append(json_obj)
```

`defaultdict` will automatically create the `"%Y-%m"` key (if it doesn't exist), initialized to an empty list.

For instance, if the `dt_obj` value in this loop iteration represents `2021-10-07 18:00:00`, then that line would look like

```py
month_data["2021-10"].append(json_obj)
```

after the string formatting is performed by the `datetime` library.

so, if the month key already exists (was added in a previous iteration of the loop), then it will append to the list mapped to that key. Because of defaultdict's magic, if the key **doesn't** exist, then it will be created and set to an empty list, which will then have the json_obj appended to it.

I hope that clarifies the code for you!

---

[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for `defaultdict`

Comment: Thanks a lot @sparrow1029, great solution, and thanks for the hint towards "DefaultDict"- didnt know that. The only thing is, that now the dates are shifted as somehow another timezone is used. Do you have a fix for that too? Otherwise sorry for the confusion. I indeed was aiming at monthly data. So your code is great!

Comment: You're welcome! Oof, timezones are no fun. There is a library called `pytz` that is very helpful and can be used in conjunction with Python's builtin `datetime.tzinfo` class to ease the pain... [This](https://benalexkeen.com/working-with-timezones-in-python/) is a good article that may help?

Comment: Thank you I solved it, works now great!!!